# DeadObjectException when I try to check external storage status

Tags: java, android

I'm facing a random crash when I try to check the status of the external storage (mounted/unmounted)

This is the condition I use to check and get the external directory if mounted

```
 if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && context.getExternalCacheDir() != null) {
```

and this is the crash I'm getting:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
at android.os.storage.StorageManager.getVolumeList(StorageManager.java:890)
at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.getExternalDirs(Environment.java:11)
at android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState(Environment.java:674)
```

Does anyone know why this keeps happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: try to update your android compile SDK

Comment: the compile SDK version I have is 27